# Making a new function by fixing one of the input parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I want to write a function `double add_100(double  x)`, and I have already written the code for `double add_two_numbers(double a, double b)`. **Note**: Here that the variable `x` is local, and hence I need to implement it in the main() function itself. I found `std::bind` could be of help, but could not get how to implement it. Another possibility I think would be `Lambda expressions` but again I am unable to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: If by 100 you mean some number you will know at run time, then you cannot make such function. However, yoy can make an `std::function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want lambda or `std::function`, or `std::bind`

```
auto l_add_100 = [](double x) { return add_two_numbers(x, 100); };
std::function<double(double)> f_add_100 = [](double x) { return add_two_numbers(x, 100); }
auto b_add_100 = std::bind(add_two_numbers, std::place_holder::_1, 100);
```

or with non hard coded number

```
double y = //...
auto l_add_y = [y](double x) { return add_two_numbers(x, y); }
std::function<double(double)> f_add_y = [](double x) { return add_two_numbers(x, y); }
auto b_add_100 = std::bind(add_two_numbers, std::place_holder::_1, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double add_100(double x)
{
   return add_two_numbers(x, 100);
}
```

Comment: The exact question is I want to make a function double f(double x), which would evaluate the value of any function at the point 'x'. But now while making such functions for polynomials in which I have an extra parameter vector<double> coeff. for storing the coefficients. Now using this how can I do it. Because for calculating f(x) I need to send it the vector<double> coeff.

Comment: @user3496912 You mean something like [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)?

Comment: @user The exact question can be read above and looks nothing like what you wrote in that comment. Instead of making a half hearted attempt to write the question, and hoping that we will read your mind, you should take more time to ask the question that you would like us to answer. Please work harder next time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am new to the community. Sorry, for the wrong portrayal of the question. I have edited the question now and will try to improve next time.

Comment: Your edit is hardly an improvement. Please try harder.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry, but I think this time I have put in a lot of effort.